# Decimal formatted number in APEX

Tags: apex, string, format

I want to format a Decimal field as a 6 digit String.

The field is a `Decimal(6,0)` and I want it to be a string of 6 characters with any necessary leading zeroes.

```
1  => 000001
2  => 000002
12 => 000012
...
```

I tried to use `String.format` but I still have my number without leading zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

Seems easy enough

Decimal with a precision of 6

```
Decimal d = 123456;
```

Add a 0 in front

```
String t = 0 + string.valueOf(d);
```

Per your requirements

but I suspect what you want is this (modified with code from sfdcfox):

```
Decimal d = 12345;

String t = (('000000')+d).right(6);
system.debug(t);
```

Comment: Or `(('0'.repeat(6))+d).right(6);`

Comment: @sfdcfox wouldn't `('00000'+d).right(6)` be a (very tiny) bit better for performance?

Comment: @Novarg Yes, I probably should have written that instead, but it was pretty late in the night when I should probably have been sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `leftPad`, which does exactly what you're looking for. You can specify the character to pad with, or it defaults to the space character (`' '`).

```
public static String get6DigitRepresentation(Decimal input)
{
    return (value == null) ? null : String.valueOf(input).leftPad(6, '0');
}
```

A similar pattern can be used to generate dummy Id values for tests:

```
@IsTest
public class DummyId
{
    public static Id generate(SObjectType input)
    {
        String counter = String.valueOf(incrementCounter(input));
        return input.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + counter.leftPad(15, '0');
    }

    static Map<SObjectType, Integer> counters = new Map<SObjectType, Integer>();
    static Integer incrementCounter(SObjectType input)
    {
        if (!counters.containsKey(input)) counters.put(input, 0);
        else counters.put(input, counters.get(input) + 1);
        return String.valueOf(counters.get(input));
    }
}
```